# Extracting values from strings.xml

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a doubt.I have an activity which contains an autocompletetextview.The contents for autocompletetextview have been declared in strings.xml file as a string array.I hav one more string array in my strings.xml file.What i want is that when i select an item from autocompletetextview it should display a value from the second string array in the form of a toast.Is it possible.Plz help me

Comment: You mean to say, if you select a item from one array then you want to display the same position item of another array in a toast right?

Answer (score 1):

**For Array::**

```
String[] myarray =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array);
```

**For String::**

```
String myString =getResources().getString(R.string.str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with this,

```
package mytest.projects;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class example extends ListActivity {
String[] mTestArray;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create an ArrayAdapter that will contain all list items
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    mTestArray =  = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray);    

    /* Assign the name array to that adapter and 
    also choose a simple layout for the list items */ 
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    mTestArray);

    // Assign the adapter to this ListActivity
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```